# Should nova-api run on different compute nodes?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I am dealing with OpenStack（Folsom) and I want to deploy OpenStack to work on different
compute nodes. Is it necessary to run Nova Api service on every node?

It seems that every compute node needs a nova-api service in my equirement, but I think it does not make sense.

In my understanding only one nova-api service is required in the hole cloud system.

Request -> nova-api -> nova-schedule to determine which node to use.

Comment: Only the nova-compute and nova-network are required one the compute node .( i don't test the scenario that using quantum). I only tried nova + glance + keystone :) the simplest group ~~

Answer (score 1):

Yes I think it is so, and according to the office guide writen by the OpenStack [Installing Additional Compute Nodes](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-compute/install/apt/content/installing-additional-compute-nodes.html) only the dependence and the nova-* component on the additional compute node should be installed or just the nova-compute package.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you only need one nova-api service running.

However, if your networking is configured for [multi-host](http://docs.openstack.org/folsom/openstack-compute/admin/content/existing-ha-networking-options.html), then you will need to run a metadata service on each compute node. In this scenario, you need to run nova-api-metadata service on each compute node.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to run Nova-API service in every compute node. But, if you are using some of the available images with cloud init script that looks for metadata from Nova API then you need to install it in every compute node.

If you can build your own VM image without cloud init scripts, then it will not be required.